# Convert array of array of objects to array of objects using JOLT

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have an input JSON something like below

```json
{
  "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Account",
  "attributes": {
    "Address": [
      {
        "value": {
          "AddressLine1": [
            {
              "value": "3169 N 5TH ST"
            },
            [
              {
                "value": "3169 N 5TH STREET"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "StateProvince": [
            {
              "value": "PA"
            },
            [
              {
                "value": "PA"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am ending up with combination of array and list of array after I merge two jsons. I want to reduce that to just list of objects using JOLT.
Any suggestions are appreciated

Trying to get output something like below

```json
{
  "type": "configuration/entityTypes/Account",
  "attributes": {
    "Address": [
      {
        "value": {
          "AddressLine1": [
            {
              "value": "3169 N 5TH ST"
            },
            {
              "value": "3169 N 5TH STREET"
            }
          ],
          "StateProvince": [
            {
              "value": "PA"
            },
            {
              "value": "PA"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dive deepest to the innermost part of the JSON within a **shift** transformation to match the innermost **`"value"`** and the value taken from one upper level(**`"@1,value"`**), and then tile the ampersand identifiers along with thier respective levels such as **&4**, **&3**, **&2** .., and wrapping them with square brackets such as **`[&2]`**, **`[&5]`** in order to get array-wise results, stated as in the following one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // all elements other than "attributes" object
      "attributes": {
        "Address": {
          "*": {
            "value": {
              "AddressL*|StatePr*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "@1,value": "&7.&6[&5].&4.&3[&2].&",
                    "value": "&7.&6[&5].&4.&3[&2].&"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]